# Just-in-Time Provisioning for Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, identity

I'm trying to configure Just-In-Time provisioning for Salesforce Communities, but can't get the pieces to talk to each other.

The process for setting JIT up for *Customer Portals* [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_jit_portal_requirements.htm&language=en_US) and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml_assertion_examples.htm&language=en_US#saml_assertion_examples_JIT), and depends on passing in the `portal_id` parameter (which isn't relevant for Communities).

This except from the [Community Implementation Guide](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) seems to suggest that `portal_id` isn't needed for JIT provisioning in Communities, but there isn't good information about what *is* required.

[image]

I've provided SAML Attributes with all of the required fields.  Authentication works properly for existing users, but does not successfully provision a new account.  Validating the SAML Assertion yields this error message:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: Having the same issue myself ... any luck?

Comment: Haven't solved it yet, sorry!